# What causes PLS-00306 when passing a 2D matrix to a stored procedure?

Tags: plsql, procedure, user-defined-types

How could I pass a matrix as parameter to a procedure. I've tried this:

```
create or replace PACKAGE MY_PKG IS
    TYPE my_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    TYPE my_matrix IS TABLE OF my_array;

    PROCEDURE PRINT_MATRIX(matrix my_matrix);
END MY_PKG ;
```

But when I call this function with a matrix as parameter, I have this error:

> ORA-06550: line 18, column 5:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRINT_MATRIX

Here is how I'm calling it:

```
declare
    TYPE my_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    TYPE my_matrix IS TABLE OF my_array;
    matrix1 my_matrix := my_matrix(); 
begin
     MY_PKG.PRINT_MATRIX(matrix1); 
end;
```

Comment: How is it not working? That appears to be a valid package specification. Please provide exactly what error you are returning.

Comment: When I call this function with a matrix as parameter, I have this error: ORA-06550: line 18, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRINT_MATRIX'

Comment: TYPE my_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TYPE my_matrix IS TABLE OF my_array;
matrix1 my_matrix := my_matrix(); MY_PKG.PRINT_MATRIX(matrix1);

Comment: Ideally, you should really post all relevant code. In this case, that would be pacakge body (specification only if somehow relevant) and exact calling code. However, I believe I see your problem. Though the datatype definitions are identical, the datatypes are not the same. Declare the variable matrix1 as type `my_pkg.my_matrix` and let me know if it still has problems.

Comment: You're right! I deleted local declaration of matrix1 and now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: @HepC - I have converted your suggestion into an answer. However, if either you or Daniel care to to post a solution yourselves I will delete mine.

Comment: @APC Thanks for letting me know, but I think it's fine. I don't need the reputation points, I just like to help. Thanks for putting a real answer in so that it is easier to see!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the local declaration of TYPE in the calling program. Although this has the same name and the same signature as the parameter internally Oracle will resolve it to a different ID. Hence the `PLS-00306` error.

The solution is to reference the type definition from the package spec when declaring a local variable.

```
declare
    matrix1 MY_PKG.my_matrix := MY_PKG.my_matrix(); 
begin
     MY_PKG.PRINT_MATRIX(matrix1); 
end;
```